# Arithmetic sequence in java. How to solve my coding? My code comes up with an output but its not the correct output

Tags: java

```java
    public class ArithSeries {
          
          public static void main ( String [] arg ) {
            
            int option, numTerms;
              double a0, difference, term;
            double [] terms;
            ConsoleInput ci;

            ci=new ConsoleInput();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("      Enter option:");
            System.out.println("       Explicit = 1");
            System.out.println("      Recursive = 2");
            while ( true ) {
              option=ci.readInt("         option = ? ");
              if ( ( option == 1 ) || ( option == 2 ) ) break;
            }
            while ( true ) {
              numTerms=ci.readInt("number of terms = ? ");
              if ( numTerms > 0 ) break;
            }
            a0=ci.readDouble("             a0 = ? ");
            difference=ci.readDouble("     difference = ? ");
            System.out.println();
            ci.close();

            for ( int i=0; i<numTerms; ++i ) {
              if ( option == 1 ) term=termExplicit (i,a0,difference);
              else               term=termRecursive(i,a0,difference);
              System.out.println( String.format("%5.2f",term) );
            }

            return;
          }

          private static double termExplicit ( int i, double a0, double difference ) {

          }

          private static double termRecursive ( int i, double a0, double difference ) {

          }
        }
```

This program is supposed to calculate and print out the terms of an arithmetic sequence.

The first method that is needed code `termExplicit` is supposed to calculate the `ith` term `ai` of the arithemtic sequence explicitly via `ai = a0 + i (difference)`

The second method `termRecursive` is supposed to calculate the `ith` term `ai` if the arithmetic sequence recursively via `ai = ai-1 + difference`. So in other words, this method should call itself.

This is what I came up with

```java
    private static double termExplicit ( int i, double a0, double difference ) {
         return a0*Math.pow(difference,i);

      private static double termRecursive ( int i, double a0, double difference ) {
         if ( i == 0 ) return difference;
         return a0+termRecursive(i-1, difference, a0);
```

For example running the program with an explicit calculation of 10 terms using `a0 = 4.8` and `difference = 7.2` gives the following output

`Enter option:   Explicit = 1  Recursive = 2  Option = 1  number of terms = 10    a0 = 4.8     difference 7.2`
The output is supposed to be this
`4.80--12.00--19.20--26.40--33.60....`

Comment: I can't actually understand your question, even though I think it's at least the third time you've asked it.  It seems odd to me that you'd use `Math.pow` when calculating an arithmetic sequence.   Maybe that's something you could reconsider.

Comment: Its not clear what is the output, and what it should be. I would strongly suggest using a debugger and stepping through your code.

Comment: @Dawood ibn Kareem  So instead of Math.pow, what should I use?

Comment: @matt  It's supposed to calculate starting from 4.8 and adding 7.2 each time. So 4.8 + 7.2 = 12 + 7.2 = 19.20 + 7.2 = 26.40 etc

Comment: You are including the input prompt as part of what you describe as the output. be also aware that when you use  `System.out.println()`it appends a new line at the end so if you don't want that in your rewsponse, your `System.out.println( String.format("%5.2f",term) );` should be `System.out.print( String.format("%5.2f",term) );` and then the separator and a newline later

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you mixed up some operators. `*` is multiplication, not addition and `Math.pow` calculates `x^y`. I think what you want is `a0 + i * difference`.

The recursion can't be called in the for-loop. Recursion is an alternative for the loop. You should pass numTerms to the recursive function so it knows when to stop. Also in the recursive call you mixed up the parameters.
I haven't tested it, but it could work like this.

```
private static double termRecursive (int i, double a0, double difference, int numTerms) {
    if (i == numTerms - 1) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%5.2f", a0));
        return 0.0;
    }
    double totalDifference = difference + termRecursive(i+1, a0, difference, numTerms);
    System.out.println(String.format("%5.2f", a0 + totalDifference ));
    return totalDifference ;
}
```